# How to unbind event only from one item in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with 3 input elements. Every element have name attribute with the same value "shipping_method" and have different id values.

```
<ul>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method_1"  class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
<label for="shipping_method_1">Method 1</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method_2"  class="shipping_method">
<label for="shipping_method_1">Method 2</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method_3"  class="shipping_method">
<label for="shipping_method_1">Method 3</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

To each element using jquery .on() event bound

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name^=shipping_method]", shipping_method_selected)
```

I can't change the code which binds the event! I have to decouple event from the second input element. I have tried to use jquery .off(), but in this case, it unbinds the events of the three elements. What are the options of unbinding events in such situations?

Comment: Which element do you want to unbind? `off` will unbind from all elements that match selector.

Comment: The second element

Comment: When should the second element have event unbound?

Comment: My suggestion would be to change how you are selecting the elements, give them a class instead and just use `removeClass();` for whichever element using it's id.

Comment: @guest271314 It doesn't matter, for example by clicking on it

Comment: @Dray i can't change how event are bind to element

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `off` you can specify which element to exclude from a selector, I've used [`:eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to deselect the second element.

```js
$('input[name^=shipping_method]:not(:eq(1))').on("change", shipping_method_selected)

function shipping_method_selected() {
 console.log('called');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method_1"  class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
<label for="shipping_method_1">Method 1</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method_2"  class="shipping_method">
<label for="shipping_method_1">Method 2</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method_3"  class="shipping_method">
<label for="shipping_method_1">Method 3</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: Exclude second input from event binding by using `:not` and the id of the second input.

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[name^=shipping_method]:not(#shipping_method_2)", shipping_method_selected);

function shipping_method_selected() {
  console.log('selected');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method_1" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
    <label for="shipping_method_1">Method 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method_2" class="shipping_method">
    <label for="shipping_method_1">Method 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method_3" class="shipping_method">
    <label for="shipping_method_1">Method 3</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't change code that bind the event. I only can unbind event afterwards

Comment: @SanyaKuzovlev Can you not `off` first then bind again?

Comment: @SanyaKuzovlev I mean you don't control how to bind to event maybe because some other code has done that. However, in your code you can first unbind by calling `$(document).off` and then bind again with the elements you are interested in?

Comment: @SanyaKuzovlev If this is also not possible then in the handler function you detect the id and if it is that of `shipping_method_2` just return from the function without executing any logic. Is it doable?

Comment: @PankajShunkla now I understand, what do you mean:) Yep this is a solution quest271314 propose.

Comment: @SanyaKuzovlev Now I don't understand what do you mean by `Yep this is a solution quest271314 propose`? :)

Comment: @SanyaKuzovlev Did it help what I suggested?